# Are as constant but not constant random variables trivial sigma-algebra-measurable? Converse?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

1. Are almost surely constant random variables trivial sigma-algebra-measurable?

These links suggest no:

http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2004&task=show_msg&msg=1121.0001

[Is a random variable constant iff it is trivial sigma-algebra-measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282282/is-a-random-variable-constant-iff-it-is-trivial-sigma-algebra-measurable)

---

This link suggests yes:

http://www.math.duke.edu/~jonm/Courses/Math219/sigmaAlgebra.pdf

Preview:

[image]

---

I really don't think a random variable $X(\omega) = 2 \ \forall \omega \in \Omega$ except for a set $A \in \mathscr F$ can ever be trivial sigma-algebra-measurable even if A has a probability of zero. Is [Dr Mattingly](http://www.math.duke.edu/~jonm/Courses/Math219/sigmaAlgebra.pdf) (same link as earlier) wrong?

---

2. What about the converse? Are trivial sigma-algebra-measurable random variables necessarily constant (that is never almost surely constant)?

Comment: All three links say that this is true. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @avid19 Sorry. Going to edit question. The third link says "almost surely constant" rather than "constant". Are almost surely constant but not constant random variables trivial sigma-algebra-measurable?

Comment: So you question is about almost surely constant vs surely constant? Surely constant are trivial sigma algebra measurable but you don't know if almost surely is as well? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @avid19 Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega = \{a,b\}$, $\mathcal F=2^{\Omega}$, $\mathbb P(\{a\})=0$, $\mathbb P(\{b\})=1$. Define $X(a)=0$, $X(b)=1$. Then $\mathbb P(X=1)=1$ so $X$ is almost surely constant, but $$X^{-1}(\{1\})=\{b\}\notin\{\varnothing,\Omega\},$$ so $X$ is not trivial $\sigma$-algebra measurable.

The converse is true. Suppose $\sigma(X)=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ and $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$ for some $x\in\mathbb R$. Then $X^{-1}(\{x\})=\varnothing$, so there is no $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $X(\omega)=x$.

Comment: Thanks Math1000. For the converse part, how do we know that X is almost surely constant but not constant? I'll edit question to clarify I mean almost surely constant but not constant.

Comment: If $X$ were almost surely constant but not constant, there would exist $x\in\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb P(X=x)$ but $X(\omega)=x$ for some $\omega\in\Omega$. If $\sigma(X)$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, this cannot be the case.

Answer (score 2):

If a r.v. is constant, you have $[X\in B]$ is empty if the constant is not in $B$ and it is $\Omega$ otherwise.  This is measurable in the trivial $\sigma$-algebra.  It if is a.s. constant, then $[X\in B]$ is either a set of zero measure or measure 1.  The completion of the trivial $\sigma$-algebra is the $\sigma$ algebra consisting of sets of full or zero measure.