# Proof: trivial sigma-algebra --> random variable has to be constant

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, constants

This is a follow up on: [Is a random variable constant iff it is trivial sigma-algebra-measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282282/is-a-random-variable-constant-iff-it-is-trivial-sigma-algebra-measurable/1282336#1282336). I wanted to comment on the solution, but, unfortunately, this is only possible from 50 reputation.

I just started learning probability theory and am struggling with the following proof:

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be some probability space and $X$ a random variable on that space. Prove the following:
If $F$ is the trivial sigma algebra then $X$ must be a constant.

Adapted from the link above (this is only the first part of the proof for the converse refer to the link):

Suppose $F=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$, and there exists $a,b \in \Omega$ such that $X(a) \neq X(b)$. Then $X^{-1}(\{X(a)\}) \notin F$, is a contradiction. It follows that $X$ is constant.

My question: Does it not have to be $X^{-1}(\{X(a)\})$ or $X^{-1}(\{X(b)\}) \notin F$?
Since one of them might still be element of $F$, no?

Thanks for any help!

Cheers, dahlai

Comment: Neither are empty and neither are all of $\Omega $, so no case work is required.

Comment: @Ian this is all I needed, apparently my mind did not take this step by itself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool. That was my question! Haha

Comment: Ian you're the man.