# Prove a thm on stopped processes given fundamental principle 'you can't beat the system'?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times, gambling

How does the **principle** below imply the **thm** below?

From Williams' Probability w/ Martingales:

---

**Principle**:

---

[image]

---

**Thm:**

[image]

---

**What I tried:**

$$E[X_{T \wedge n} - X_0 | \mathscr{F_m}] =/ \le X_{T \wedge m} - X_0 \ \forall m < n$$

$$\to E[X_{T \wedge n} | \mathscr{F_m}] =/ \le X_{T \wedge m}$$

$$\to E[X_{T \wedge n} | \mathscr{F_0}] =/ \le X_{T \wedge 0} \ \text{by choosing m = 0}$$

$$\to E[X_{T \wedge n}] =/ \le X_0$$

$$\to E[E[X_{T \wedge n}]] =/ \le E[X_0]$$

$$\to E[X_{T \wedge n}] =/ \le E[X_0]$$

I think $X_0$ is constant [and](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282282/is-a-random-variable-constant-iff-it-is-trivial-sigma-algebra-measurable) $\mathscr{F}_0$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Choose the process $C$ so that $(C\cdot X)_n=X_{T\wedge n}-X_0$, which is what you did.

Intuition: To obtain the stopped-at-$T$ process, you want to keep betting so long as time $T$ hasn't yet passed.

Comment: I think that's what I did?

Comment: John Dawkins, your bet is 1 unit per round?

Comment: Yes, 1 unit per round up until time $T$.

Comment: Thanks John Dawkins. So my proof is right?