# Asymmetric Random Walk / Prove $E[T] = \frac{b}{p-q}$ / How do I use hint?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Given random variables $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots \stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim} P(Y_i = 1) = p = 1 - q = 1 - P(Y_i = -1)$ where $p > q$ in a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)$ where $\mathscr F_n = \mathscr F_n^Y$,

define $X = (X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ where $X_0 = 0$ and $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$

Let $b$ be a positive integer and $T:= \inf\{n: X_n = b\}$. It can be shown that:

1. [$T$ is a $\{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$-stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562632/asymmetric-random-walk-prove-that-t-inf-n-x-n-b-is-a-mathscr-f) s.t. [$E[T] < \infty (\to T < \infty \ \text{a.s.})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562635/asymmetric-random-walk-prove-that-et-inf-n-x-n-b-infty)
2. [$$E[X_{T \wedge n}] = (p-q)E[T \wedge n]$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560804/asymmetric-random-walk-prove-ex-t-wedge-n-p-qet-wedge-n)
3. $M = (M_n)_{n \ge 0}$ where $M_n = X_n - n(p-q)$ is a ($\{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)-$martingale.

> Prove $E[T] = \frac{b}{p-q}$. Hint: Consider $|M_{n+1} - M_n|$

---

I'm not sure how to use the hint, but I think I was able to prove the proposition anyway:

---

**Attempted Proof 1:**

$$\because E[X_{T \wedge n}] = (p-q)E[T \wedge n]$$

we have by DCT that

$$E[X_{T}] = (p-q)E[T]$$

where

$$E[X_{T}] = E[b] = b$$

$$\therefore, E[T] = \frac{b}{p-q} \ QED$$

Is that right?

---

**Attempted Proof 2:**

$$M_T = X_T - T(p-q) = b - T(p-q)$$

$\because M$ is a martingale and $E[M_i] = 0$, we have $E[M_T] = 0$.

$$\to E[T] = \frac{b}{p-q} \ QED$$

Is that right?

---

**Attempted Proof 3:**

$$X_{T \wedge n} = \sum_{i=1}^{T \wedge n} Y_{i+1}$$

$$M_{T \wedge n} = \sum_{i=1}^{T \wedge n} (Y_{i+1} - (p-q))$$

$$\to M_{T \wedge n} = X_{T \wedge n} - (T \wedge n)(p-q)$$

$$\to \lim M_{T \wedge n} = \lim X_{T \wedge n} - \lim (T \wedge n)(p-q)$$

$$\to M_{T} = X_{T} - (T)(p-q)$$

Thus, I reinvented the wheel. Is my reinventing right?

---

**I'm not sure what the hint is supposed to do:**

$$|M_{n+1} - M_n| = |Y_{n+1} - (p-q)| \le 1 + p - q$$

$$\to M_{T \wedge n} \le (1 + p - q)(T \wedge n) = T \wedge n + E[X_{T \wedge n}]$$

$$(?) \ \to M_{T} \le (1 + p - q)(T)$$

How can I use the hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Attempted Proof 1 is wrong because DCT doesn't apply. Maybe $X_{T \wedge n}$ is not bounded by an integrable random variable.

Attempted Proof 2 uses Doob's Optional-Stopping Theorem (c) $(*)$:

$$E[X_{T \wedge n}] = (p-q)E[T \wedge n]$$

$$|M_{n+1} - M_n| = |Y_{n+1} - p + q| \le 1 + p - q = K$$

Consider previsible process $C_n = 1$

Use Doob's Optional-Stopping Theorem (c) $(*)$ on $(C \cdot M)$ to get:

$$E[(C \cdot M)_T] = 0$$

$$\to E[M_T] - E[M_0] = 0$$

$$\to E[M_T] - 0 = 0$$

$$\to E[M_T] = 0$$

$$\to E[X_T - T(p-q)] = 0$$

$$\to E[X_T] - E[T(p-q)] = 0$$

$$\to E[X_T] = E[T(p-q)]$$

$$\to E[X_T] = (p-q)E[T]$$

$$\to E[b] = (p-q)E[T]$$

$$\to b = (p-q)E[T] \ QED$$

---

$(*)$ Doob's Optional-Stopping Theorem:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---