# Theory of random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Let 0 < p < 1 and let $S_n$ be the simple random walk with step probabilities p, 1 − p.

In other words $S_n = X_1 + · · · + X_n$ and the {$X_i$} are i.i.d. random variables with distribution
$$P(X_i =1)=p \qquad and \qquad P(X_i =−1)=1−p$$
Fix a positive integer b > 0, and let T be the first hitting time of the point b:
T(w) = inf{n ≥ 1 : $S_n(w)$ = b}.
If the walk never hits b, in other words the set {n : $S_n$(w) = b} is empty, then T(w) = $\inf$.

How could I find ET?

Comment: Think averages. On average the walk moves $2p-1$ up. If $2p-1\le 0$, $E(T)=\infty$. Otherwise, $(2p-1)E(T)=b$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little.

Comment: $M_n=S_n-n(2p-1)$ is a martingale. If $ET_b<\infty$ then $E(M_{T_b})=0$. You are left to note that $S_{T_b}=b>0$.

Comment: @A.S. Cmiiw, but to say in the first place that $(2p-1)E[T] = b$ [assumes that $E[T] < \infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560867) ?

Comment: Matt Smith, I'm trying to answer that problem too. I think we should use this proposition: https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=e9saZ0YSi-AC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=%22what%20always%20stands%22%20%22probability%22&source=bl&ots=AWEio5s6Xq&sig=6kAyfQZorHRSFhYEVjQ83V7XGU4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje6t-I0MTJAhUleaYKHUa7AfIQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22what%20always%20stands%22%20%22probability%22&f=false