# Application of Doob's optional stopping theorem to an elementary probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

The elementary probability problem is as follows.

> Let $(X_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $X_k \sim U(0,1)$ for each $k$. Define $\tau := \inf\{n\geq 0: \sum_{i=1}^n X_i > 1\}$. What is $E[\tau]$?

There are plenty of clever solutions to this problem. However, I would like to find a solution that utilizes Doob's optional stopping theorem. I don't know if such a solution exists by the way. I am doing this out of sheer curiosity.

To make life easier I will just assume that $E[\tau] < \infty$. I can prove this later on. So I define $Y_n$ to be
$$Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
Then the compensated process $Z_n := Y_n - \frac{n}{2}$ is a martingale.
By hypothesis we have that $Y_{\tau} > 1$ and $Y_{\tau - i} \leq 1$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots,\tau-1$. By optional stopping we have $E[Z_{\tau}] = 0$ (There are a few intermediate steps here that I did not mention but the statement is fine). This yields the bounds
$$E[\tau] > 2 \qquad E[\tau] \leq 3$$

Of course we know that $E[\tau] = \exp(1)$. At least the bounds make sense but how do I make them tighter, better yet how do I make the lower and the upper bounds equal?

Comment: Maybe my [question and answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560867/asymmetric-random-walk-prove-et-fracbp-q-how-do-i-use-hint) here will help?