# Verifying my understanding of sigma algebra generated by multiple random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have seen quite a few posts but it seems not many answered the question correctly. So I am a bit confused.

My Understanding:
Given $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and $(R,B(R))$;
let $X$, $Y$ be random variables that $X,Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$

$$\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma\left(X^{-1}(B_i)\bigcap Y^{-1}(B_j)\right) = \{ \omega \in \Omega: (X(\omega),Y(\omega)) \in (B_i, B_j)\}  \in  \mathcal{A} \tag1$$

Or in plain english: $\sigma(X,Y)$ is a sigma algebra that is generated by sets of $\omega$ that satisfy $X(\omega) \in B_i$ and $Y(\omega) \in B_j$ at the same time

Then my gut tells me that because the preimage of the intersection is the intersection of the preimages, which means $$\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma\left(\sigma(X) \bigcap \sigma(Y)\right)$$

I used the following example to test (1) and (2) and it did work
$$ X(\omega) = 
\begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in \{tt, hh\} \\
0 & \omega \in \{th, ht\}
\end{cases}
$$

$$ Y(\omega) = 
\begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in \{tt, hh\} \\
2 & \omega \in \{th\} \\ 
3 & \omega \in \{ht\}
\end{cases}
$$

$$\Omega = \{tt,hh,th,ht\}$$

Am I correct with (1) and (2)

Comment: $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(\sigma(X) \bigcup \sigma(Y))$. Also, $X(\omega) =B_i$ does not make sense.

Comment: @geetha290krm I am positive $\sigma(X \bigcup Y) = \sigma(\sigma(X) \bigcup \sigma(Y))$ So $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(X \bigcup Y)$?

Comment: @geetha290krm $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(\{tt,hh\}, \{th\}, \{ht\})$ and $\sigma(\sigma(X) \bigcup \sigma(Y)) \neq \sigma(\{tt,hh\}, \{th\}, \{ht\})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of arbitrarily many $\sigma$-algebras is a $\sigma$-algebra, so $\sigma(\sigma(X)\cap \sigma(Y))=\sigma(X)\cap \sigma(Y)$. As pointed out by @geetha290krm in the comments, the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by random variables $X$ and $Y$ is $\sigma(X,Y):=\sigma(\sigma(X)\cup \sigma(Y))$. We can then see that $\sigma(X)\cap \sigma(Y)\subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$. However, the reverse inclusion is not true in general. Consider $X,Y:([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]))\to ([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]))$ where $X(\omega)=0$ and $Y(\omega)=\omega$. Then
$$\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,[0,1]\},\,\sigma(Y)=\mathscr{B}([0,1])$$
So $\sigma(X)\cap \sigma(Y)=\{\emptyset,[0,1]\}$, but $\sigma(X,Y)=\mathscr{B}([0,1])$.

Comment: Ok, I think I am more confused now. As for one of the example I was given in lecture (illustrated in the question), $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(\{tt,hh\}, \{th\}, \{ht\})$ and it seems not from union but intersection

Comment: @TJT $\sigma(X,Y):=\sigma(\sigma(X)\cup \sigma(Y))$. This is well known. It is also true that for real-valued rvs, $\sigma(X,Y)=\sigma(\{\{X\in A,Y \in B\};A,B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\})$. However, we have seen that $\sigma(X)\cap \sigma(Y)\subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$, while the reverse can be false.

Comment: I see. My claim was that $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma\left(\sigma(X) \bigcap \sigma(Y)\right)$ which should be right as well right since $\sigma(X)\cap \sigma(Y)\subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$

Comment: Your claim is false in general; there is an example in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I work through the example and see it now. One last thing,  I also encountered $\sigma(X \bigcup Y) = \sigma(\sigma(X) \bigcup \sigma(Y))$ before. Does this mean $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(X \bigcup Y)$ as well?

Comment: @TJT the notation $\sigma(X\cup Y)$ is not precise in my opinion; what would $X\cup Y$ mean? I would rely on the definition $\sigma(X,Y):=\sigma(\sigma(X)\cup \sigma(Y))$.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much indeed for your help!

Comment: @Snoop : In your counter-example to JT, why is $\sigma(X)$ different from $\sigma(Y)$. I realize that everything maps to zero in the case of $X$ but $\omega$ can still be anything in [0,1] ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds we can see that $\{\omega\in [0,1]:Y(\omega)\in B\}=\{\omega\in [0,1]:\omega\in B\}=B$ for any Borel set $B$ so $\sigma(Y)=\{B:B\in \mathscr{B}[0,1]\}=\mathscr{B}[0,1]$

Comment: @Snoop: I do get that but can you be bothered to do the same thing for $\sigma(X)$. Thanks and my apologies for being a pest.

Comment: @markleeds no worries, that is a legit question. Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282282/is-a-random-variable-constant-iff-it-is-trivial-sigma-algebra-measurable), and let me know if this convinces you.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look. The link is appreciated.

Comment: It does convince me. That link was quite enlightening in all sorts of ways. Thanks a lot.